# one or more verb agreement

Tags: verb-agreement

Sentence: A recent review of our records indicates that one or more of your dependents ***does/do*** not have a valid birthday on file

This is actually for a business letter and we have conflicting opinions in the office if the verb should be "does" or "do". Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Go ahead and have your argument, but why not find a way round it that avoids the disagreement?

> A recent review of our records reveals that **at least** one of your dependents does not have a birthday on file

The direct answer to the question is that there is little to choose between the two.  I should marginally go for the singular.  On thing, however, is certain:  whichever way you jump between singular and plural, some readers will think you made a mistake.  So ‘at least’ is safer.